# Unable to add the value from dropdownlist to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I created a form to store information about the customers and his membership type. For that I am using the drop down list to hold values for membership types. But on submitting the form, the value(Id) for membership type isnt added to database

```
//Model Membership Types
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }

//ViewModel NewCustomerviewModel
public IEnumerable<MembershipTypes> MembershipTypes { get; set; }
public Customers  Customers{ get; set; }

//Controler CustomerController
public IActionResult Index()
{
 var customers = _context.Customers.Include(c => c.MembershipTypes).ToList();
 return View(customers);
}

[HttpPost]// Create is the aciton for Submit Button
public IActionResult Create(Customers customers)
{
 _context.Customers.Add(customers);
 _context.SaveChanges();
 return RedirectToAction("Index", "Customers");
}


//View Model
@model Wes.ViewModels.NewCustomerviewModel;
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Customers.MembershipTypes, new SelectList(Model.MembershipTypes, "Id", "Name"),"Select Membership Type", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

When the Form is Submitted, it should add all the values to the database including the value of Drop Down List Membership Types

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing it this way:

```
//model
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public enum MembershipTypes 
    {
    Type1,
    Type2,
    Type3
    }
public MembershipTypes _membershipTypes {get; set; }
```

```
//controller
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create([Bind("Id","Name","_membershipTypes")] Customers customers)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(customers);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }    
    Return View(customers);    
}
```

```
//view
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <form asp-action="Create">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.DropDownList("_membershipTypes",
                    new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(MembershipTypes))),
                    "Select membership type",
                    new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit!" />

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi.. The value are being fetched from the database and assigned to the Drop Down List, and when the option is selected, that value is assigned to the customer database with corresponding customer

Comment: Right. What I'm saying is that, in my method, the dropdown values (membership types) are just listed in the MembershipTypes enum, and those types (in my example, Type1, Type2, Type3) populate the dropdown menu. When you submit the form, the selected type is stored in the database with the corresponding customer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show more about the relationships(one-to-one,one-to-many) of your models.

The parameters of your post action need to correspond with the model of your view,use `NewCustomerviewModel` instead of `Customers`.

The dropdownlist shows the type of name and pass id as value to action, so your `asp-for` of dropdown list needs to be set for an id or id list.

Refer to my demo which pass id list of `MembershipTypes` to action using multiple select.

1.My ViewModel `NewCustomerviewModel`,

```
public class MembershipTypes
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class NewCustomerviewModel
{
    public int[] SelectMembershipTypesId { get; set; }
    public Customers Customers { get; set; }
}

public class Customers
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MembershipTypes> MembershipTypes { get; set; }
}
```

2.Create `GET` action

```
public IActionResult Create()
    {
        var model = new NewCustomerviewModel()
        {              
            Customers = new Customers()
            {
                MembershipTypes = _context.MembershipTypes.ToList()
            },

        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

3.Create `POST` action

```
[HttpPost]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Create(NewCustomerviewModel viewmodel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            viewmodel.Customers.MembershipTypes= _context.MembershipTypes
                                                 .Where(m =>viewmodel.SelectMembershipTypesId.Contains(m.Id))
                                                 .ToList();
            _context.Add(viewmodel.Customers);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(viewmodel);
    }
```

4. Create View

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectMembershipTypesId,
                    new SelectList(Model.Customers.MembershipTypes, "Id", "Name"), "Select Membership Type",
                    new { @class = "form-control", @multiple = "multiple" })
```